# Building sepia theme for mobile browser using CSS

Tags: css, safari-extension, browser-extension, css-filters, ios-darkmode

I am building an **iOS Safari extension** that inverts to different themes (Gray, Dark, and Sepia). Gray and Dark work well, but it doesn't work as expected for the **Sepia** one. It change colors of not only the background, but also the content of the page.
[Here's the image with the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q64EG.jpg), I want it not to invert the page content, and [Here's the target image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/624lB.png)

And this is my css files I inject to the page.

```
/* sepia.css */

body {
    background-color: rgb(246, 240, 229) !important;
    filter: sepia(1) !important;
}
```

```
/*dark.css*/

body {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;
    filter: invert(1.0) hue-rotate(165deg) !important;
}

img,
video {
    filter: invert(1.0) hue-rotate(-165deg) !important;
}
```

```
/*gray.css*/

body {
    background-color: rgb(75, 75, 75) !important;
    filter: invert(0.85) hue-rotate(165deg) !important;
}

img,
video {
    filter: invert(0.85) hue-rotate(-165deg) !important;
}
```

And this is the javascript code I use to send (inject) the css file to the website.

```
//popup.js

insertCSS("sepia.css");

function insertCSS(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        browser.tabs.insertCSS({ file }).then(resolve, reject);
    });
}
```

Comment: You seem to be filtering everything in body. If you want to filter only the background you need to show that separately from the body (e.g. on a pseudo element). Please show enough code in your question so we can see the problem - where/how is the target image displayed? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I **edited the post** with more code, please check it again.